# Import cv2.py error; cannot install Python cv2

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I'm trying to run this Python script on a Mac:

`https://github.com/jasonlfunk/ocr-text-extraction/blob/master/extract_text`

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2.cv
```

I have OpenCV installed on the Mac. I have checked that the PATH to /site-packages/ is working. The package 'cv2' is just not installed. However, if I try to install it, I get the error:

```
pip install pyopencv
Collecting pyopencv
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyopencv (from versions: 2.0.wr1.0.1-demo, 2.0.wr1.0.1, 2.0.wr1.1.0, 2.1.0.wr1.0.0, 2.1.0.wr1.0.1, 2.1.0.wr1.0.2, 2.1.0.wr1.1.0, 2.1.0.wr1.2.0)
  Some externally hosted files were ignored as access to them may be unreliable (use --allow-external to allow).
  No distributions matching the version for pyopencv
```

I don't know python - appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing OpenCV using `brew`, probably it will install python wrapper as well. Alternatively you can try using `pip install pyopencv --allow-external`, sometimes this options solves the problem (at least on windows).

Comment: I couldn't get anything on a Mac to work. In the end I used the python-opencv official docker image, which worked out of the box. https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/ibotdotout/python-opencv/

Answer (score 0):

I always use this when I install opencv:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

I hope it helps you.